# TableView doesn't show rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I am working with parse on a little app. It should show names, where stored on parse user class in an Array column.

Here is my Code:

```
@synthesize friendsList;

-(void)viewDidLoad{ 
[super viewDidLoad];

    PFQuery*query = [PFUser query];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"myObjectId" block:^(PFObject   *gameScore, NSError *error) {

    if(error==nil){

        friendsList = [gameScore valueForKey:@"Friends"];

        NSLog(@"%@", friendsList);

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }

}];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView      numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [friendsList count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = friendsList[indexPath.row];

return cell;
 }
```

The problem is, when I am loading the data from parse. It does't show anything on the table view.

Do I declare friendsList likt this:

```
friendsList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name1", @"Name2",  nil];
```

It will work.

Comment: What is the name of the column ?

Comment: Did you print [gameScore valueForKey:@"Friends"]; and got an array of values??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tableView` is blank as your `friendsList` is not populated when the tableView is displayed.

In the completion block reload the tableView.
In your completion block after `friendsList = [gameScore valueForKey:@"Friends"];` statement add following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData]; // assuming your table view is tableView
            });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed allocating the array

```
friendsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```